# To determine Nullity of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq  n$ . And  $ T : V \rightarrow \mathbb R ^{m}$ be defined as $T (P (x)) =  (P (1) , P (2) ,..., P (m) )$

I have to determine nullity of $T$ .

Here for nullity I see I have to make two separate cases when $n> m$ and $n<m$ .Also for nullity I set $P (1) =0 , P (2) =0\cdots$ but i am not getting clear along these lines .Please help me to get through this .Thanks

Comment: Note that $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\vec 0$ iff each $x_i=0$.

Comment: If m is less than n+1 , then how do i process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide the two cases as:

Case 1: $m>n$

Here we have a homogeneous system with more equations than unknowns, hence we get a unique solution, i.e if $P\in\ker T$ then $P=0$, i.e $\dim\ker T=0$

Case 2:$m\leq n$

Here we have less equations than number of unknowns. If $P\in\ker T$ From $m$ equations (since $P(1)=0,P(2)=0,...,P(m)=0$) we get $m$ relations among the coefficients of the $n$ degree polynomial $P$. Hence $\dim\ker T =n-m+1$

Comment: I am almost clear , just can you exlplain  how the rank is m in second case

Comment: This answer completely ignores the possibility of dependencies between equations. For instance "hence we get a unique solution" is too fast, once cannot deduce this just by counting equations and unknowns.

Comment: lets give an example @SophieClad $n=2,m=2$ so if we have $P=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$ we get  2 equations viz.$a_0+a_1+a_2=0$ and $a_0+2a_1+4a_2=0$ then deduce the relations between $a_0,a_1,a_2$ try for $m=1$..

Comment: is it all right now ?

Comment: Yes thanks for help

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 3):

### Revised answer

**Theorem.** *Given pairwise distinct numbers $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and any choice of $\alpha_0, \alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists one and only one polynomial $p$ of degree at most $n$ such that*
$$
p(x_0)=\alpha_0,p(x_1)=\alpha_1,\dots,p(x_n)=\alpha_n
$$

This solves the so-called “interpolation problem“. We don't need to determine it, but it can be done with the [Lagrange method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

*Proof.*
Write the unknown polynomial as
$$
\beta_0+\beta_1x+\dots+\beta_nx^n.
$$
Then applying the requirements $p(x_k)=\alpha_k$ (for $k=0,1,\dots,n$), we get a linear system with coefficient matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_0 & x_0^2 & \dots & x_0^n \\
1 & x_1 & x_0^2 & \dots & x_1^n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & x_n & x_n^2 & \dots & x_n^n
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is a Vandermonde matrix, having nonzero determinant. $\square$

Now we apply the theorem to your case. Let's write $T_m\colon V\to\mathbb{R}^m$ for the mapping
$$
T_m(p)=(p(1),p(2),\dots,p(m))
$$
and, for $r\ge s$, we consider the (linear) map $h_{r,s}\colon\mathbb{R}^r\to\mathbb{R}^s$ defined by
$$
h_{r,s}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_r)=
(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_s)
$$
In particular, $h_{r,r}$ is the identity map. Note also that $h_{r,s}$ is surjective.

The theorem above states that the map $T_{n+1}$ is bijective.

Now, suppose $m\le n+1$. Then it's easy to verify that
$$
T_m=h_{n+1,m}\circ T_{n+1}
$$
so $T_m$ is surjective as the composition of two surjective maps. Since the image has dimension $m$, the nullity of $T_m$ is
$$
\dim V-\dim\operatorname{Im}T_m=n+1-m.
$$

If $m>n+1$, we can see that $h_{m,n+1}\circ T_m=T_{n+1}$, which is injective, so also $T_m$ is injective and its nullity is $0$.

Thus we can write
$$
\dim\ker T_m=\max\{n+1-m,0\}.
$$

---

### Original answer

It's a known fact that, given $n+1$ numbers (distinct or not) $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$, there exists exactly one polynomial $p$ of degree at most $m$ such that
$$
p(0)=\alpha_0,p(1)=\alpha_1,\dots,p(n)=\alpha_n
$$
This is the “interpolation problem”. Instead of $0,1,\dots,n$ one can use any set of pairwise distinct numbers $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n$.

As a consequence, if $m\le n+1$, the map you're given is surjective. Since the dimension of $V$ is $n+1$, the nullity is $(n+1)-m$.

If $m>n+1$, then the above result implies that the map is injective.

[For details on the interpolation problem, see the “revised answer” part.]

Comment: How to determine nullity from this matrix

Comment: @SophieClad You don't determine nullity from this matrix. This matrix shows that the map $T$ is bijective when $m=n+1$; as a consequence of this, $T$ is surjective when $m\le n+1$ and injective when $m>n+1$.

Comment: While the ingredients are there, I find this answer hard to read, which I think is because of the desire to use the _same_ result for both cases. The use of $n,m$ is confused, and does not correspond to that in the question (where the number of evaluation points is $m$). In the first part you use that interpolation of $m$ vaules can be done with degree${}<m\leq n+1$; the second part uses that  $P$ having $m$ zeros implies $P=0$ when $\deg P<n+1<m$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I've revised the answer, using more formal methods, which I believe can be instructive, albeit more abstract than “direct” computation. Note that the fact that a polynomial having more zeros than its (formal) degree is zero is not used.

Answer (score 0):

Ince $\dim V=n+1$ you get from rank-nullity that $\def\rk{\operatorname{rk}}\dim(\ker T)=n+1-\rk(T)$, where $\rk(T)\leq\dim(\Bbb R^m)=m$. This, together with non-negativity of dimensions, gives the lower bound
$$
  \dim(\ker T)\geq\max(n+1-m,0).
$$
I turns out this bound is always sharp (the "$\geq$" may be replaced by "$=$"). To prove that, consider two cases (overlapping for $m=n+1$):

1. $m\geq n+1$, so that the right hand side is $0$. We must show that $T$ is injective: it cannot produce $0$ for a nonzero polynomial $P$. This is so because $T(P)=(0,\ldots,0)$ would mean that $1,2,\ldots,m$ are roots of $P$, which is too many roots for a nonzero polynomial of degree${}<n+1\leq m$ to have.
2. $m\leq n+1$. Now equality is obtained if and only if $\operatorname{rk}(T)=m$, in other words if $T$ is surjective. This is indeed the case, because one can always produce a polynomial of degree${}<m$ (so a fortiori of degree${}<n+1$) with $m$ prescribed values in $m$ distinct points, by [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).